# Using GCC toolchain in android device

Tags: java, android, c

I want to use GCC toolchain in android device and compile c or c++ in android terminal.  Like C4droid,CPPdroid these app compile in the device.

I have got the toolchain for android . Copied it in the data folder so I can execute that .

Next I drive to the path of GCC/bin used this command in terminal emulator .I copied the test.c in the bin folder. The test.c is a simple program printing hello world.

```
./arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o test test.c
```

The error I am getting is

```
error executing \libexec\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\6.1.0\cc1 :execv 
permission denied
```

And firstly I am using the command "su" so that I get full access.

Point to be noted: I have executed a c program from the same directory and it worked. So this may not be a permission problem I think.

Comment: It looks like it is a cross-compiler, intended to run on your Linux PC.

Comment: So how does C4droid compiles C program in the device ? And I have took the same gcc that C4droid uses.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how the hierarchy and inheritance of permissions work in the android/Linux environment. You mentioned you put the toolchain in /data, so you will have to make sure you have sufficient ownership and permissions set. Since you have root, you should be fine by settings permissions recursively from the top most common parent directory. In this case I believe you'd use 
chmod 755 -R /path-to-toolchain